# Scroll view on UITableView cell text field

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to scroll view when focus on text box which is in table view cell. 
I want to get the y of the text field, currently I am retrieving as per cell. but I want it, as per view.

Currently I have hard coded the values.

```
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;

aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
CGRect cellRect = activeField.frame;
cellRect.origin.y = 350;

if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, cellRect.origin) ) {

    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, cellRect.origin.y - kbSize.height);

    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];

}
```

Is there is any posibility to get filed height as per view.

Comment: Why not implement UItextView instead of UIScrollView inside the UItableViewCell??

Comment: I want to create a login form in list style.. I have created a custom cell contain label and a text field.. TableView is in scroll view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you scroll to the cell using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` instead of scrolling the view itself...

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

Comment: I think need to change teble size too?

Comment: but when I select directly on textbox of the cell. didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called. how to resolved this issue

Comment: What is called is "- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField" if you implement the "UITextFieldDelegate"

Comment: yes, but in this function I am getting the selected field, not the index path of the row, I need index path to scroll?

Comment: Set the indexPath.row as the textView.tag and you got it ;-)

Comment: I'm sure that you are clever enough to codify two integers into one... (for example, considering won't be more than 100 rows for section do: 100*section + row...)

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat animatedDistance;
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 215;
static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 140;

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];
    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;
    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }
    else
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
    [toolbar setAlpha:1];
    [tbl setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, [tbl contentOffset].y + 1.35*animatedDistance )];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to hardcode the keyboard size. You should get the keyboard dimensions from the Notification (UIKeyboardWillShowNotification)